# sliding window approach in Python

Tags: python, sliding-window

I have a dataframe DF, with two columns A and B shown below:

```
A                    B                  
1                    0             
3                    0               
4                    0                   
2                    1                    
6                    0                    
4                    1                     
7                    1                 
8                    1                     
1                    0
```

First part: A sliding window approach should be performed as shown below. I need to calculate mean for column B in a sliding window of size 3 sliding by 1 position . The mean values for each window are calculated manually and shown on the left side.

```
    A:         1    3    4    2    6    4    7    8    1                                          
    B:         0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    0                                
              [0    0    0]                                              0
                    [0    0    1]                                        0.33
                          [0    1    0]                                  0.33
                                [1    0    1]                            0.66
                                      [0    1    1]                      0.66
                                            [1    1    1]                1
                                                 [1    1    0]           0.66
output:        0   0.33 0.33 0.66   0.66    1     1    1   0.66
```

Second part :Now, for each row/coordinate in column A, all windows containing the coordinate are considered and should retain the highest mean value which gives the results as shown in column 'output'.

Detailed explanation for second part:The first part is calculating the mean in a sliding window 3 sliding by 1 position.  The second step is: For each coordinate 'i' in column A, all windows containing the coordinate 'i'  should be evaluated and retain the highest mean score.  For example in column A, 1 is present only in the first window, so the score for 1 is 0 (which is the mean of the first window). Similarly, 2 is present in first and second window, therefore the score for 2 should be the highest among the scores of window1 and window2 i.e. max(0, 0.33333). Likewise 3 is present in first,second and third windows, therefore score for 3 is max of the scores of first three windows i.e. max(0,0.333333,0.3333333). 4 is present in second,third and fourth windows, therefore score for 4 is max of the scores of those windows i.e. max(0.333333,0.3333333,0.666667)and so on..

I need to obtain the output as shown above. The output should like:

```
A                   B                  Output   
1                   0                      0
3                   0                      0.33
4                   0                      0.33
2                   1                      0.66
6                   0                      0.66
4                   1                      1
7                   1                      1
8                   1                      1
1                   0                    0.66
```

Any help in python would be highly appreciated?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: dataframe as in `R`? as in `pandas`? as in your own using `numpy`? as in your own, using python `list`s?

Comment: I don't understand the second part. For example, why is the fourth value equals to 0.66?

Comment: @shx2 Lets say it is a tab delimited text file with two columns

Comment: It's still unclear for me... Why, for the same value of A, output isn't always the same?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, using `numpy`:

```
WS = 3
B = numpy.array([0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0])
filt = numpy.ones(WS) / WS
mean = numpy.convolve(B, filt, 'valid')
```

For the second part:

```
paddedmean = numpy.zeros(mean.size + 2 * (WS - 1))
paddedmean[WS-1:-(WS-1)] = mean
output = [numpy.max(paddedmean[i:i+WS]) for i in range(mean.size+WS-1)]
```

But what is `A` used for???

Comment: The second part is now better explained in the original question.

Comment: @Charled Brunet: A is later used to plot a graph. The second line of the second part shows an error:                                                                                                         
                                                                        >>> paddedmean[WS;-WS] = mean
                                                                                  File "<stdin>", line 1
    paddedmean[WS;-WS] = mean
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Now it says "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7) into shape (5)"

Comment: Ok, I didn't tested my code well, and did some typo. But you could make the effort to think a little bit... It's not so complicated.

Comment: Sorry. Anyways, if there are some NA's in the vector B, then would it be possible to ignore the NA values and slide only through numeric values?

Comment: That's another question. First, search for an answer by yourself (hint: numpy masked array), and if you're blocked, ask your question in another thread.